# Cannot Remove all evicted pods in all Kubernetes namespaces Cronjob

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubectl, kong, kubernetes-cronjob

My Kubernetes cluster has memory pressure limits that I need to fix (at a later time).

There are sometimes anywhere from a few evicted pods to dozens.
I created a Cronjob spec for clearing up the evicted pods. I tested the command inside and it works fine from powershell.

However, it doesn't matter if I specify a namespace in the spec or not, deploy it to every namespace that exists, the script doesn't seem to delete my evicted pods.

Original Script:

```
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: delete-evicted-pods
spec:
  schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: kubectl-runner
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command: ["sh", "-c", "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector 'status.phase==Failed' -o json | kubectl delete -f -"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I tried creating the script with associated RBAC, with no luck either.

```
kind: Role
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  namespace: development
  name: cronjob-runner
rules:
- apiGroups:
  - extensions
  - apps
  resources:
  - deployments
  verbs:
  - 'patch'

---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cronjob-runner
  namespace: development
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: sa-cronjob-runner
  namespace: development
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: cronjob-runner
  apiGroup: ""

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: sa-cronjob-runner
  namespace: development
---
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: delete-all-failed-pods
spec:
  schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-cronjob-runner
          containers:
          - name: kubectl-runner
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command: 
              - /bin/sh
              - -c
              - kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector 'status.phase==Failed' -o json | kubectl delete -f -
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

I realize I should have better memory limits defined, but this functionality was working before I upgraded k8s to 1.16 from 1.14.

Is there something I'm doing wrong or missing? If it helps, I'm running in Azure (AKS).

[image: All Namespaces Pods]

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like after the upgrade this:

```sh
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector 'status.phase==Failed'`
```

is not picking up your failed pods anymore. It could be:

- kubectl/apiserver version mismatch
- credentials/service account permissions
- (?)

You can try running a debug pod to verify:

```sh
$ kubectl run -i --tty --rm debug --image=bitnami/kubectl:latest --restart=Never -- get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector 'status.phase==Failed'
```

Every Job in Kubernetes creates a Pod, so you can also look at the logs for your `kubectl-runner` pods:

```sh
kubectl logs kubectl-runner-xxxxx
```

Update:

Based on the log files it looks like the `default:default` service account doesn't have enough permissions this would fix it:

```sh
kubectl create clusterrolebinding myadmin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:default
```

But then if you'd like to be more restrictive you will have to create a more limited ClusterRole or Role (if you want it limited to a namespace)

Comment: Got back as response:
Error from server (Forbidden): pods is forbidden: User "system:serviceaccount:default:default" cannot list resource "pods" in API group "" at the cluster scope
pod "debug" deleted
pod default/debug terminated (Error)

Comment: Is apiGroup supposed to be empty?

Comment: I just updated the answer. Looks like this might fix it: `kubectl create clusterrolebinding myadmin-binding --clusterrole=cluster-admin --serviceaccount=default:default`

Answer (score 4):

Your role need to change to a `ClusterRole` because you are using `--all-namespaces` in the kubectl command

```
kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cronjob-runner
rules:
- apiGroups: [""] # "" indicates the core API group
  resources: ["pods"]
  verbs: ["get", "watch", "list"]
```

And the `RoleBinding` that you have is for a service account `sa-cronjob-runner` in `development` namespace. But the cron you are running is actually is in `default` namespace. Hence it's using the `default` service account from `default` namespace.

So either specify namespace `development` in the cronjob and `serviceAccountName: sa-cronjob-runner`

```
apiVersion: batch/v1beta1
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: delete-evicted-pods
  namespace: development
spec:
  schedule: "*/30 * * * *"
  failedJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          serviceAccountName: sa-cronjob-runner
          containers:
          - name: kubectl-runner
            image: bitnami/kubectl:latest
            command: ["sh", "-c", "kubectl get pods --all-namespaces --field-selector 'status.phase==Failed' -o json | kubectl delete -f -"]
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Or change the rolebinding to bind the ClusterRole to `default` service account in `default` namespace

```
---
kind: RoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cronjob-runner
  namespace: development
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: default
  namespace: default
roleRef:
  kind: Role
  name: cronjob-runner
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
```

Answer (score 0):

Even you can use this command to delete all the device pods across namespaces

> kubectl get pods --all-namespaces | grep Evicted | awk '{print $2 " --namespace=" $1}' | xargs kubectl delete pod --force